# Mark label with star if corresponding form element is required using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following part of code:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="controller.login(username, password, controller.language)" novalidate>
       <label for="username">{{"username" | translate}}</label>
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username" required maxlength="15">
       <label for="password">{{"password" | translate}}</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" maxlength="80" >
       <button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">{{"submit" | translate}}</button>
</form>
```

I'm looking for solution to mark dynamically all corresponding labels with a star (i.e. required field) for all those form elements (no matter input, textarea, checkbox or radio) which are required, most desirable by using AngularJS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6sgjo6kc/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('markRequired', function() {
    return {
      restrinct: 'A',
      require: "^form",
      scope: {
        for: "@",
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr, form) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return form[scope.for]
        }, function(newVal) {
          console.log(newVal);
          if (newVal.$validators && newVal.$validators.required) {
            element.addClass('required');
          }
        });
      },
    }
  });
```

```css
label.required:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="controller.login(username, password, controller.language)" novalidate>
    <label for="username" mark-required>{{"username" }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username" required maxlength="15">
    <label for="email" mark-required>{{"email" }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" ng-model="email" maxlength="15">
    <label for="password" mark-required>{{"password" }}</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" maxlength="80" required>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">{{"submit" }}</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more than useful! But is there option not to add additional directive within html label tags ("mark-required" I mean), just to find the link between form element and corresponding label?

Comment: You need somewhere invoke your function in `html`. Use directive is are best way.

Comment: I'm update [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/6sgjo6kc/). Check it.

Comment: Great solution, this was what I looking for, thanks!

Comment: If my answer solve your problem, please check my answer as correct.

Comment: Already did it, but need to earn enogh reputation. :) Just one more question - is it possible to extend built-in Angular form directive, i.e. not to use additional directive within form tag even, but to make it as standard (default) functionality for all forms into the project?

Comment: I don't think that we can extend form for this behavior. Because we use not angular form. We use the html form.